# dataclass not validating composite class when intialising

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I am currently working with dataclasses which a class is a composite of another. The code below should have resulted in an error and it did not.

```
@dataclass
class kk:
    p: int
    tr: int

@dataclass
class xx:
    x: int
    y: int 
    kq: kk


somkq = kk(p=1, tr=3)
somxx = xx(x=1, y=2, kq=somkq)
print(somkq)
print(somxx)

x_dict = {"x":1, "y":2, "kq":{"pk":1, "tr":3}}
print(xx(**x_dict), asdict(xx(**x_dict)))
```

My thoughts on why an error should occur:
Per default, `xx(**dict_obj)` should have raised a `TypeError: __init__() ...` since it was not defined "pk" in kq.

Comment: Dataclasses do not do *any* sort of validation, nor do they care about instantiating attributes as classes.

Answer (score 0):

Regular dicts have no validation like you are looking for. In fact I can do:

```
class KK:
    p = 1

k = KK()
k.q = 2
```

Now `k` has 2 attributes `p` and `q`.

What you might want to do is use `pydantic`.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class KK(BaseModel):
    p: int
    tr: int


class XX(BaseModel):
    x: int
    y: int
    kq: kk
```

Now

```
x_dict = {"x":1, "y":2, "kq":{"pk":1, "tr":3}}
print(xx(**x_dict))
```

will throw a pydantic ValidationError.

Finally, I don't think this line: `somkq = kk(p=1, tr=3)` in your example works. The class `kk` cannot be instantiated unless you add a `def __init__()`.